# Scriptable way of changing collations for all text columns in a SQLite database

Tags: sqlite, scripting

I have a sqlite database file which has a few hundred tables; I need to change the table definitions so that all of the text columns have the RTRIM collation (they're all currently just default).

Is there some easy way of scripting this? I'm not that familiar with SQLite itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the following C++ program seems to mostly work for me (might depend on how exactly the tables were created in the first place, not sure if SQLite 'normalizes' the CREATE TABLE statements it stores internally?)

I open the file containing the tables, ATTACH a new database (which will contain the modified tables), get the table definitions, do some crude text manipulation (only works because in my case the columns didn't have an explicit collation) to add the 'COLLATE RTRIM', then create those tables in the attached database & copy the contents of the existing tables into them.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "sqlite3.h"

#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

void exec(sqlite3* db, const char* sql)
{
    sqlite3_stmt* res;

    int rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &res, 0);

    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {

        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to prepare \"%s\": %s\n", sql, sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        sqlite3_close(db);
        exit(1);
    }

    rc = sqlite3_step(res);

    if (rc != SQLITE_DONE) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Executing \"%s\" failed: %s\n", sql, sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        sqlite3_finalize(res);
        sqlite3_close(db);
        exit(1);
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(res);
}

vector<string> GetTables(sqlite3* db)
{
    sqlite3_stmt* res;

    const char* sql = "SELECT name FROM main.sqlite_master WHERE type='table';";
    int rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &res, 0);

    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {

        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to prepare \"%s\": %s\n", sql, sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        sqlite3_close(db);
        exit(1);
    }

    vector<string> result;
    while (SQLITE_ROW == (rc = sqlite3_step(res)))
    {
        result.push_back((const char*)sqlite3_column_text(res, 0));
    }

    if (rc != SQLITE_DONE) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Executing \"%s\" failed: %s\n", sql, sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        sqlite3_finalize(res);
        sqlite3_close(db);
        exit(1);
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(res);

    return result;
}

string GetTableDefinition(sqlite3* db, const char* name)
{
    sqlite3_stmt* res;

    const char* sql = "SELECT sql FROM main.sqlite_master WHERE name = ?";
    int rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &res, 0);

    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {

        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to prepare \"%s\": %s\n", sql, sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        sqlite3_close(db);
        exit(1);
    }

    rc = sqlite3_bind_text(res, 1, name, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {

        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to bind parameter %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        sqlite3_close(db);
        exit(1);
    }

    vector<string> result;
    while (SQLITE_ROW == (rc = sqlite3_step(res)))
    {
        result.push_back((const char*)sqlite3_column_text(res, 0));
    }

    if (rc != SQLITE_DONE) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Executing \"%s\" failed: %s\n", sql, sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        sqlite3_finalize(res);
        sqlite3_close(db);
        exit(1);
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(res);

    if (result.size() != 1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "We didn't get exactly 1 row\n");
        sqlite3_finalize(res);
        sqlite3_close(db);
        exit(1);
    }

    return result[0];
}

bool StartsWith(const string& toCheck, const string& prefix)
{
    return (toCheck.size() >= prefix.size()) && !toCheck.compare(0, prefix.size(), prefix, 0, prefix.size());
}

string FixTableDefinition(const string& in_tableDef)
{
    regex r("TEXT([,)])");
    string result(regex_replace(in_tableDef, r, "TEXT COLLATE RTRIM$1"));
    if (!StartsWith(result, "CREATE TABLE "))
    {
        abort();
    }

    result.insert(strlen("CREATE TABLE "), "NEW.");
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    sqlite3* db;

    int rc = sqlite3_open("c:\\perforce\\Drivers\\SEN\\Maintenance\\10.2\\SQLiteDSII\\C++\\Product\\Setup\\DBF\\SEN\\SEN.dbf", &db);
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {

        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        sqlite3_close(db);

        exit(1);
    }

    exec(db, "ATTACH DATABASE 'c:\\perforce\\Drivers\\SEN\\Maintenance\\10.2\\SQLiteDSII\\C++\\Product\\Setup\\DBF\\SEN\\new.dbf' AS 'NEW'");

    const vector<string> tables(GetTables(db));
    for (const auto& table : tables)
    {
        const string tableDef = GetTableDefinition(db, table.c_str());
        const string fixedTableDef = FixTableDefinition(tableDef);
        exec(db, fixedTableDef.c_str());
        exec(db, ("INSERT INTO  NEW." + table + " SELECT * FROM main." + table).c_str());
    }

    sqlite3_close(db);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```